# que permita login solo cuando el usuario es activo

Tags: php, login

En mi BD en la tabla user el campo de activo es is_active, lo que necesito es que con este script me autentique solo los que is_active = 1, gracias

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] !== '') {

    //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    include "../config/config.php";

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["email"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $password = sha1(md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["password"], ENT_QUOTES)))));    

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email =\"$email\" OR username=\"$email\" AND password = \"$password\";");

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {          

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        header("location: ../dashboard.php");
    } else {
        $invalid = sha1(md5("contrasena y email invalido"));
        header("location: ../index.php?invalid=$invalid");
    }
} else {
    header("location: ../");
}

?>
```

Comment: <?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token'] !== '') {

    //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    include "../config/config.php";

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["email"], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $password = sha1(md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["password"], ENT_QUOTES)))));    
    
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email =\"$email\" OR username=\"$email\" AND password = \"$password\";");

Comment: if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {          

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        header("location: ../dashboard.php");
    } else {
        $invalid = sha1(md5("contrasena y email invalido"));
        header("location: ../index.php?invalid=$invalid");
    }
} else {
    header("location: ../");
}

?>

Comment: Amigo puedes añadir tu codigo editando la pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/99203/edit)

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon ahí tu código, no como comentario.

Comment: Podrías describir mas claro que es lo que deseas lograr? Y agrega el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añádele la condición para que coja el que cumpla esas condiciones y además esté activo...

```
 "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ="$email" OR username="$email" AND password = "$password" AND is_active = 1"
```

PD: Edita el post, que no se entiende casi...

Comment: Gracias amigo, el tema es que lo hago así y me lo aplica cuando el login es solo con el username, pero si se hace el login con el email si pasa aunque el usuario este inactivo

Comment: Solucionado, gracias

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email= \"".$user."\" or username= \"".$user."\") and password= \"".$pass."\" and is_active=1");